# Rename column with a name from a list

Tags: python, pandas

for example i have a list of name:

```
name_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and 3 dataframes:

```
>> df1
>>    k   l   m
   0  12  13  14
   1  13  14  15

>> df2
>>    o   p   q
   0  10  11  12
   1  15  16  17

>> df3
>>    r   s   t
   0  1   3   4
   1  3   4   5
```

What i want to do is to replace the first column from each dataframe with a each name from name_list. So, a will replace k, b will replace o and c will replace r.

the output will be:

```
>> df1
>>    a   l   m
   0  12  13  14
   1  13  14  15


>> df2
>>    b   p   q
   0  10  11  12
   1  15  16  17

>> df3
>>    c   s   t
   0  1   3   4
   1  3   4   5
```

i can do it manually but would be better if there is best method to do it. Thanks

Comment: With those three DataFrames just floating around you are going to need to do it manually. Had they been in a container, like a dict or list, then you could do it with less typing

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @ALollz but nevertheless you can try something like

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=['k', 'l', 'm'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=['o', 'p', 'q'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=['r', 's', 't'])

name_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for index, name in enumerate(name_list, 1):
    df = pd.eval('df{index}'.format(index=index))
    df.rename(
        columns = {
            df.columns[0]: name,
        }, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dataframes in a list like `dfs = [df1, df2, df3]` then you can do:

```
dfs = [dfs[i].rename(columns={dfs[i].columns[0]: name_list[i]}) for i in range(0,len(dfs)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in place:

```
[df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: c}, inplace=True)
 for df,c in zip([df1,df2,df3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

Alternatively:

```
for df,c in zip([df1,df2,df3], ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: c}, inplace=True)
```